# Best structure to use both seleniumbackedrc and webdriver

Tags: automation, selenium-webdriver, structure

We have recently moved to Selenium Web Driver. We have loads of tests written in selenium Rc which are now working fine using webdriverbackedselenium API. Now I am planning to move to web driver. Can you please guide what the is best approach to shift. Either completely move the code to use web driver but it requires a lot of effort. Or use both. It means I need to keep wrapping and unwrapping the driver. Totally confused about the layout of structure. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how your old tests were organized. If you used Page Object Pattern in your old tests migration to WebDriver should not be so difficult. Just create base class for all your page model classes and put in it all the logic that you need to initialize your page instance using Page factory. After that you can rewrite old page classes one by one preserving old interface in order to reduce amount of changes in the tests.